# PHP to work across templates in Joomla

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla

I'm trying to get a small set of php functions working that i need available on the entire page. I'm including them in my index.php main template via `require_once "my_functions.php"`.

They work in the index.php template; that's the good news.

We have a plugin that let's us write php in our content items with the following syntax:
`{source}<?php echo "hello world!"; ?>{/source}`

However, when trying to use the functions defined in my_funcitons.php, php thinks they're unavailable and generates a fatal error `... undefined method or function`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe you should write a module, implement your `require_once` inside it and [insert the created module in articles](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F).

Avoid creating too much php code in WYSIWYG editors, you're mixing content with programming logic, defeating CMS's purpose: manage content. And if you have non-technical people behind your system this can become a real headache in the future.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create content plugins for each of the features you're trying to incorporate, then have those plugins scan the article for tokens that you replace with markup: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_content_plugin

Comment: Yeah, I forgot he could use some plugins too. It's a good approach too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Direct PHP](http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/DirectPHP-plugin.php).

Comment: if i use `require_once "my_functions.php"` in the content pages it will work.

This is not really a solution though because the functions are also needed in the main index.php file.

I don't want to include them twice or be forced to include them in every single content item.